# Devexprees grid view click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I have created a gridview using Devexpress control. I want to display ProductID in alert box on click on ProductName in the grid cell.
**Controller.**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        string commString = "";

        public HomeController()
        {
            FWUtility.connString = "Data Source=DEVELOPER1; Initial Catalog=FR8DemoDB; uid=**; pwd=***";
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            commString = "select ProductID,ProductName from ProductMaster";
            List<ProductMaster> listProductMaster = FWUtility.GetList<ProductMaster>(FWUtility.GetDataTable(commString));
            return View(listProductMaster);
        }
    }
    public class ProductMaster
    {
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View.**

```
function OnCellClick(e) {
        var name = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        alert(name['ProductID']);
    }
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "myGridView";
            settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index" };
            settings.Width = 450;
    settings.Columns.Add("ProductName");
            settings.HtmlDataCellPrepared = (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.Cell.Attributes.Add(
                        "onclick", "OnCellClick();"
                );
            };
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

"**item** is undefined" this is the error I am getting on click.Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All DevExpress MVC Extensions exposes a number of [client-side events](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#aspnet/CustomDocument9150), allowing you to respond to end-user manipulations without server processing.

So if you are talking about the GridView, please use the [GridViewClientSideEvents.RowClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebGridViewClientSideEvents_RowClicktopic) event as follows:

```
function OnRowClick(e) {  ...   }
...
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
        //...
        settings.ClientSideEvents.RowClick= "OnRowClick";
    }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```